# more question related to calisthenics / bodyweight training

Tags: discussion

Due to this worldwide pandemic, many people have started practicing bodyweight training/calisthenics, thanks to the closure of gyms.

I've seen that there are not many places on the Internet with good quality content related to the Calisthenics world.

How could we do to receive more questions related to the calisthenics / bodyweight training?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, we get a lot of bodyweight/callisthenic questions. The problem I find is that no one ever seems to like the answers. It always seems like people want to look like Phil Heath and they're disappointed when a pure calisthenics program isn't making them monstrously muscular in 2 months. What do you mean I have to change my eating habits? Blasphemy.

And if you're coming from a heavy weight training routine at the gym to a resistance-bands-from-Walmart home-workout routine, the sad truth is you're gonna lose gains.

Rant aside, if you've got a specific bodyweight question that hasn't been asked before (try searching `[bodyweight-exercises]` or `[home-exercise]` first) feel free to ask it. Lots of really experienced individuals are knowledgeable in body-weight exercises.

Comment: That's true, I mean people with no experience tend to be more  likely to start bodyweight training in this period,  but without some dietary precautions it is almost impossible to drastically change your body. BTW the point of my question is that the bodyweight training community is not as developed as that of weight training and information is often thrown at random without a minimum of research and reliability. In this community I found many people (as you said) very well prepared on the subject. So why not try to expand in this direction too?